# Add date to data dump download

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

[Current StackExchange data dumps](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) are available via torrents:

[image]

However, there's no reference of the extraction date; you have to [find this in the FAQ at the bottom of the page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). Would it be possible to add the date as part of the download button or just somewhere visible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The update date on Data Explorer reflects the last time the data in the public Data Explorer instance was updated and is different than the date of [the data dump which the torrent represents](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), which at the time of posting reflects data as of 2014-01-20.

I'm not opposed to making the data dump update date more clear, but I'm not sure that there's any good way to get the relevant value in this case since it's unconnected from the one you referenced in your request.

Comment: I just added a date to show what I mean (it will be incorrect in a week anyway).

Comment: I was just clarifying that the date listed in the FAQ doesn't have anything to do with the torrent.