# Update frequency of SE Data Dump on Web Archive

Tags: support, data-dump, archive

Since there's is [no clear indication of the data-dump date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218212/168244), a visit to the [Stack Exchange Data Dump on the Web Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) is dated May 2, 2014:

[image]

How frequently is this archive updated?

Comment: Well, it says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) "roughly every three months" so it's already a month late. I fear that "roughly" is kind of like 6-8 weeks, so it might take long time before they update.

Comment: They just [uploaded a fresh dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240139/stack-exchange-september-2014-data-dump-is-available), in case you missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data dump is updated every 3 to 4 months.  We do update the date on the metadata when it's finally published and ready for download.

Comment: The latest dump seems to be from more than an year ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269760/200117 || http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254271/latest-stack-exchange-data-dump-on-internet-archive-not-latest

Comment: The current dump is Jan 4-5 2016, just last week. I have filed a bug in the archive.org JIRA about the .torrent not being up-to-date.

Comment: The problem is that the Internet Archive doesn't make .torrent files for any item bigger than 25 gigabytes. And, unfortunately, we don't delete any older .torrent when this happens, so that's how it ended up with an obsolete .torrent.