# Stack Exchange September 2014 Data Dump is available

Tags: discussion, data-dump

The complete Stack Exchange data dump up to September 2014 is ready and can be found hosted on the Internet Archive.  The latest can always be found here:

https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

The torrent is now available here:

https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent

It takes a bit of time for archive to process the massive amount of data we send their way.

Enjoy sharing and remixing, but remember to attribute the source if you publish your own versions of this data.

Comment: Is it possible to [answer this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239147/168244) now that a new release is available?