# Latest stack Exchange data dump on internet archive not latest

Tags: support, data-dump

At first, there was a problem downloding with the torrent, as you can see in the comments area [here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). More specifically, the downloading of stackoverflow dump data got stuck. A few days later the downloading seemed to work. However,

When I ran `tail -n 10 Posts.xml`, I got

[image]

The `creationDate` suggests this is probably the last dump (september, 2014). Data dump from other sites seems to be current although I only verified with small sites like `apple.stackexchange.com`.
How did this happen? And more importantly, can it be fixed?

EDIT:

I took another look at the files I downloaded. 
[image]

Its Data Modified appears to be wrong. In comparsion for `apple.stackexchange.com`,
[image]

This one seems to be correct.

Comment: What is the sort order of the content in Posts.xml? Perhaps *not* by date?

Comment: Related post on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289795/having-troubles-downloading-the-data-dump/289813#289813

Comment: @Werner I took a look at the extracted stackoverflow Posts.xml file, its date modified is sept 17, 2014. So I think they have the wrong file after all...

Comment: @rene Thanks! I'm downloading the individual files now. Gonna take a long time. :(

Comment: @Werner I've done `grep 2014-10 Votes.xml` to verify that, and no results: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269760/200117 2014-09 is the latest it seems.