# When was the last data dump uploaded to archive.org?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

The publishing date on [archive.org/details/stackexchange](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) is 16th March 2015

> Stack Exchange Data Dump by Stack Exchange, Inc.
>
> Published March 16, 2015
>
> Usage Attribution-Share Alike 3.0

However, the files appear to be newer than that, the time stamps from [archive.org/download/stackexchange/](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/) indicate August, except the Comments and Badges files which are April.

```
stackoverflow.com-Badges.7z                      09-Apr-2015 19:28     90.9M
stackoverflow.com-Comments.7z                    09-Apr-2015 19:42     2.0G
stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z                 18-Aug-2015 15:49     12.0G
stackoverflow.com-PostLinks.7z                   18-Aug-2015 15:50     35.6M
stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z                       18-Aug-2015 16:52     7.3G
stackoverflow.com-Tags.7z                        18-Aug-2015 16:52     573.1K
stackoverflow.com-Users.7z                       18-Aug-2015 16:54     153.0M
stackoverflow.com-Votes.7z                       18-Aug-2015 16:58     500.1M
```

I've imported all the data with the stack dump offline browser, which reported a large number of inconsistently errors, I'm guessing from the mixing an old comment file with newer post file.

Is this a mistake? Where can I find a consistent set of files? Unfortunately I cannot access bit-torrent from where I work.

Comment: Strange. It's now labelled as being from August, but when I downloaded the torrent file it was the same as the one released in March...

Comment: I filed a bug in the internal archive.org JIRA for this issue.

Comment: The problem is that the Internet Archive doesn't make .torrent files for any item bigger than 25 gigabytes. And, unfortunately, we don't delete any older .torrent when this happens, so that's how it ended up with an obsolete .torrent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good way to estimate the age of the *data* (true, not the same as upload date, maybe some format changed, but likely what most people want), is to download `Votes.xml` ("only" 400M compressed) and:

```
tail Votes.xml
```

This shows to me that the latest dump that I've just downloaded was from `2014-09`.

Then I've done:

```
grep 2014-10 Votes.xml
```

to confirm, and got no results as expected.

So this seems to be the one from this announcement: [Stack Exchange September 2014 Data Dump is available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240139/stack-exchange-september-2014-data-dump-is-available)

I've found a few questions mentioning that the data is outdated or that the date is not clearly documented:

- [Add date to data dump download](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218212/add-date-to-data-dump-download?lq=1)
- [Update frequency of SE Data Dump on Web Archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239147/update-frequency-of-se-data-dump-on-web-archive)
- [Latest stack Exchange data dump on internet archive not latest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254271/latest-stack-exchange-data-dump-on-internet-archive-not-latest)

Answer (score 4):

In the data obtain via bittorrent from https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent
the latest post from stackoverflow that I saw was from 2014-09-14 03:07:29 UTC.

However, the zip archive https://archive.org/compress/stackexchange/formats=7Z&file=/stackexchange.zip had posts from 2015/08.