# Add the DeletionDate column to the archiv.org data dump or create a PostsWithDeleted table

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

The latest [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) has:

- no `DeletionDate` column
- no `PostsWithDeleted` table

but it *does* contain deleted posts.

This makes it hard to decide if posts are deleted or not.

I think I could extract that from the `PostHistory` table `Deleted` and `Undeleted` events, but that is much more inefficient.

Please either:

- add a `DeletionDate` column. I prefer this method as it makes things easier to query.
- add a `DeletionDate` column, removed deleted posts, and create a `PostsWithDeleted` table. This is exactly what the SEDE does now, so at least things would be uniform. But from the query writer point of view, this method is just more complicated.

Maybe SEDE and dump got out of sync because the current dump it too old? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269760/200117 Add a more recent one pleaase :-)

Comment: The dump does not contain deleted posts. It *does* contain posts which may have been deleted since it was created.

Comment: @Oded ahhh... I think you are right... doh!

Comment: @downvoters: let me know what I should do with this question and I will. I't rather not delete so that some other newbs like me can find it.